# VueJS: How to retrieve information from a table with checkboxes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Im learning vue.js so the question seems to be very basic. Apologies in advance. I have a table with several rows, that contains a checkbox and a text. I want to know how can i get the data from the rows that have the checkbox selected only

I am using axios to send that information, but i had not luck by now.See my code below:

```
       <table class="table table-hover">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col">Status</th>
             <th scope="col">Keyword</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr v-for="item in msg">
           <td>
              <input type="checkbox" id="defaultCheck" name="example2">
              <label for="defaultCheck"></label>
           </td>
             <td>{{item.Keyword}}</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
       <button v-on:click="getFormValues">Submit</button>
       </form>
     Output: {{ output }}
```

Then i have this:

```
export default {
  name: 'Keywords',
  data() {
    return {
      output: '',
    };
 methods: {
    getFormValues () {
      this.output = this.$refs.my_input.value
    },
  }
```

The button triggers the event, but it does not seem to send any data. How can i send the array of items that have been selected in the table?

Does anybody have an example on how can i do this please?

Thanks

Comment: You are not setting any refs in the inputs

Answer (score 3):

You can use `v-model` for this

```
<tr v-for="item in msg">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="defaultCheck" name="example2" v-model="output" :value="item">
    <label for="defaultCheck"></label>
  </td>
</tr>

export default {
  name: 'Keywords',
  data() {
    return {
      output: [],
    };
 methods: {
    getFormValues () {
      console.log(this.output)
    },
  }
}
```